# JToolBar in window

Tags: java, swing, jtoolbar

I have a JToolBar that is currently on the border but can be put in its own smaller window if dragged over. I want to have this JToolBar start in the window rather than me having to drag it out. I did some research and the few other examples of this said that I should implement BasicToolBarUI but I have no idea how to use it. Can I get any recommendations for this problem?

Comment: Can you upload some code?  Its one of the guidelines...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement BasicToolBarUI, you need to use methods from the UI.

```
JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar();
BasicToolBarUI ui = (BasicToolBarUI)toolBar.getUI();
ui.setFloatingLocation(300, 300);
ui.setFloating(true, null);
```